# SUM and COUNT xPath expression doesn't work in Oracle 11.2

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, plsql

I have a problem running some - rather simple - xPath queries in Oracle (11g R2) containing `SUM` and `COUNT` functions. For example:

```
select extractvalue(
                    xmltype.createxml('<a>
                                         <b>
                                           <c>1</c>
                                           <d>XXX</d>
                                         </b>
                                         <b>
                                           <c>2</c>
                                           <d>YYY</d>
                                         </b>
                                       </a>')
                    , 'sum(/a/b/c)'
                    ) 
  from dual;
```

same for `count`:

```
select extractvalue(
                    xmltype.createxml('<a>
                                         <b>
                                           <c>1</c>
                                           <d>XXX</d>
                                         </b>
                                         <b>
                                           <c>2</c>
                                           <d>YYY</d>
                                         </b>
                                      </a>')
                   , 'count(/a/b/c)'
                   ) 
   from dual;
```

I am getting `ORA-31012` in response. Any idea how to get it working? Or what could be a possible workaround?

Answer (score 3):

I don't recall the last time I've been using `extractvalue` as it is depracated in 11g. Instead I'm using [`xmlquery`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions253.htm):

Here's a simple example how to `count` and `sum`:

```
with 
xmldata as (
  select xmltype('<a><b><c>1</c><d>TEXT1</d></b><b><c>2</c><d>TEXT2</d></b></a>') as data_ from dual
)
select 'COUNT', xmlquery('
count($doc/a/b/c)
' passing data_ as "doc" returning content) as result_
from xmldata
union all
select 'SUM', xmlquery('
sum($doc/a/b/c)
' passing data_ as "doc" returning content) as result_
from xmldata
;
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: The problem is that I am given ready xPath expression according to the standard. Addig something like '$doc' somewhere in the middle is a bit problematic. For example in expression like: count(/a/b/c) + sum(/a/b/d). I would have to play with text parsing in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the answer from @user272735 without using `as "doc"` and removing `$doc` and it seems to work the same:

```
with 
xmldata as (
  select xmltype('<a><b><c>1</c><d>TEXT1</d></b><b><c>2</c><d>TEXT2</d></b></a>') as data_ from dual
)
select 'COUNT', xmlquery('
count(/a/b/c)
' passing data_ returning content) a as s result_
from xmldata
union all
select 'SUM', xmlquery('
sum(/a/b/c)
' passing data_ returning content) as result_
from xmldata
;
```